# Seeking VIIRS Day Night Band and alternatives for night satellite images

Tags: data, remote-sensing, satellite

Has anyone worked with VIIRS Day Night Band?

I want to download few
images to get a map of night scene of Central Europe (city lights etc).
I use friendly interface at NOAA (http://www.class.ncdc.noaa.gov/saa/products/search?datatype_family=VIIRS) and I've downloaded few images already. The problem is that there was only one nice image and the rest of them were in 95% covered with
value 0 (although they were taken in the same night!).

My questions are:

- Is there any way to preview VIIRS Day Night Band images before download?
- Does mosaic of night scene images for Europe already exist and is available for download?
- Do you have any other ideas where to find remotely sensed images of earth at night?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've got some help from NOAA. If someone needs an info about VIIRS images download:
The best way to preview images is to preview Meteosat geostationary browse imagery. The 0000Z time IR images would be sufficient.  This is aa website for previewing images:  http://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/gibbs/year . 
You can also visit http://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/NPP/news/earth-at-night.html and downloiad the high resolution map of the globe.

The first link helped me to check if night on certain datum had a lot of clouds. So I was able to avoid downloading bad images.